# Angular, Do we need to make service singleton or by default it works as a singleton?

Tags: service, angular8

I am working with angular 8 version to create a e-commerce application.
Want to share same data between components like product and wishlist.
So for that, Is service works like singleton by default or I have to make changes to make it singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Service is not work as singleton by default.
There are 2 ways by which we can make it singleton

1. To create a singleton service is to set providedIn to root on the service's @Injectable() decorator

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

2. Or we can add in providers in NgModule of root module (AppModule)

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [UserService],
})
```